# Why is searching in <200 categories slower than searching in >6000 products?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, query-optimization

Using line_profiler library to analyse my Django Ecommerce project, I find that searching in less than 200 Product Categories is *slower* than searching in over 6000 Products.

As you can see in the image below, using a .get() method on the ProductCategory objects takes more than double the time of using .filter() on the Products, even though the Product.filter has to look through a list of values (categories__in).

Does anyone have an idea as to why this is? :-))

[image]

Comment: `.filter()` is lazy: it will not make a database query unless you consume the result.

Comment: Hmm. Would there be a way to optimize the ProductCategory.get() by using filters, then? For example ProductCategory.filter(slug=self.slug[0])?